# How can I protect a module variable that should only be readable through a pointer in fortran?

Tags: fortran, global-variables, protected

I have an example program that looks like this:

```
module important_module

integer, dimension(5), protected, target :: important_array
contains
function testFunction() result(important_array_pointer)
  integer, dimension(:), pointer    :: important_array_pointer

  integer        :: i

  do i = 1, size(important_array)
    important_array(i) = 0
  end do
  important_array_pointer=>important_array
  
end function testFunction

end module important_module

Program TEST

    use important_module
    integer, dimension(:), pointer    :: important_array_pointer

    important_array_pointer=>testFunction() 
    print *, important_array_pointer(1) ! prints 0
    important_array_pointer(1) = 1
    print *, important_array_pointer(1) ! prints 1

End Program TEST
```

I would like `important_array` to only be writable from within the `important_module` module, hence the `protected` definition. This is because this array is used in conjunction with the [fortran FFTW interface](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Overview-of-Fortran-interface.html#Overview-of-Fortran-interface) and holds information where a fourier transform is performed on, and it's suboptimal to have the input- or output arrays of these operations be public or be accessible from anywhere outside of this module. This example simplifies this as a 1d integer array.

If I generate a pointer to this array, it still becomes writable from the outside, even though I expected some kind of violation error.

Is there a way to ensure that this variable is actually protected and cannot be written to from anywhere outside of the corresponding module?

Comment: Your program violates the Fortran standard, but not in a way that a compiler is required to (be able to) detect. There are plenty of ways using pointers to do naughty things, and this is just one of them.

Comment: What would you suggest `testFunction` would look like then? Is the only way here to return a copy of `important_array` and accept the performance decrease as a consequence?

Comment: `testFunction` currently exists, with that pointer, in such a way to remove all burden for checking from the compiler (recall, the programmer is always responsible for whether a program is valid or not). If your question isn't so much the "why", but how to write `testFunction` to safely do what you want to do, then can you write more detail on what it is you want to do? (There are ways to write a secure something, but some could be wildly inappropriate for what you need.)

Comment: During development/debugging you may use compilation option that enable all possible runtimes checks: this comes with a performance hit, but it can help tracking invalid instructions.

Comment: @francescalus I edited the question to further clarify what the actual problem with this setup is.

Comment: On this exemple, making a copy of the array would be fully reasonnable, as the performance hit of a 5 elements copy is negligible.

Comment: @PierU The real example is a 5 dimensional tensor with 1.000.000+ data points, which makes copying rather time intensive

Comment: I was close to understanding what you are after until I got to "it's suboptimal to have the input- or output arrays of these operations be public or be accessible from anywhere outside of this module". If you don't want them to be public or accessible outside the module, don't make them public (by default) and don't make them targets and provide a module procedure which generates a pointer to them and exposes that pointer to anyone that asks.

Comment: What I think I do understand though, is that you want to provide extra hints to the compiler that allows it to detect the inappropriate attempts to modify, rather than protect against malicious end users. Correct?

Comment: @francescalus yes this is primarily to make sure it is not accidentally modified from the outside. These variables are already not public, but having a pointer point to them makes them "unofficially" public in a way. The result of an FFTW transform is also a `pointer` and not a `target` object like in this example, which still leaves this vulnerability of other pointers point to it like in the example function I supplied.

Comment: The actual size was worth mentioning... Why don't you simply remove the `target` attribute? The read access from outside of the module be will be just by using the module. Returning a pointer is really not needed here.

Comment: From your piece of code, the array is public (no private attribute visible). So I understand that you meant it is private...

Comment: Does a user of the module really need to access the array as a whole? Or just some elements?

Comment: @PierU only some elements need to be accessed. Adding the `private` attribute to `important_array` did not change the program behaviour

Comment: In modern Fortran, pointers are "almost always the wrong thing to use". Reading the comments I'm pretty much of the view that what you want here isn't one of the exceptions and that you are perhaps misunderstanding what visibility and accessibility are in modules (as PierU may also be intimating). I'll bow out of commenting for now to avoid making things noisier and confusingier.

Comment: There are not many options if you want the data to be accessible, protected against writes, and without copying everything... 1) the array is public and protected, without the target attribute, and the user the module just uses it. 2) the array is private, and you provide a function that returns selected elements only with a copy.

Answer (score 0):

To start, I agree with @francescalus about pointer usage in Modern Fortran. To me, it is still not clear why you are using a pointer to that important variable you want to protect, approach you clearly noticed, it does not protect your variable as you'd like.

If possible, I would remove the `target` attribute.

But in the case you *have to* keep it, then the only (to my knowledge) way is to build an interface layer on top of it:

```fortr
module important_module

    implicit none
    private
    public :: testfun

    integer, parameter :: array_size = 5
    integer, target :: important_array(array_size)

contains

    function testfun() result(important_array_pointer)
        integer, dimension(:), pointer :: important_array_pointer
        integer :: i

        do i = 1, array_size
            important_array(i) = i
        end do
        important_array_pointer => important_array
    end function

end module important_module


module interfmodule

    use important_module
    implicit none
    public
    integer, pointer, protected :: var_interf(:)

contains
    subroutine setVarPtr()
        var_interf => testfun()
    end subroutine
end module


Program TEST
    use interfmodule
    implicit none

    call setVarPtr()
    print *, var_interf(3)
    print *, var_interf(4)

    ! ! Trying to write gives error !
    ! var_interf(2) = 10
End Program TEST
```

Comment: What error do you expect to see with `var_interf(2) = 10`?

Comment: @francescalus indeed gfortran gives an error if the line is decommented *"Error: Variable 'var_interf' is PROTECTED and cannot appear in a variable definition context (assignment) at (1)"*. However, one just has to create another pointer `foo => var_interf`, and then writing to it gives no error `foo(2) = 10` --> OK. All this stuff with pointer is complicated and doesn't protect anything at the end. Again, the simplest way to really protect `important_array` and make it readable is to declare it `publlic`, `protected`, and without the `target`attribute.

Comment: @PierU, oh, thanks. Have you reported that compiler bug to the developers? (`var_interf` is a pointer, so it's allowed to appear in a variable definition context; it's prohibited from appearing in a pointer association context.)

Comment: @francescalus Not clear: which one is a compiler bug for you?

Comment: @PierU, rejecting `var_interf(2) = 10`. The PROTECTED attribute for a pointer restricts changing where the pointer points, it doesn't restrict changing the value of the pointer's target. That assignment statement doesn't change the pointer association so is allowed

Comment: @PierU yes, you're right. Creating another pointer pointing to `var_interf` breaks as usual. But, then, the last thing that come to my mind is not using `var_interf` directly, instead hiding it behing a *getter* function. Do you agree?

Comment: @PierU , btw, it gives error also using Intel ifort 2021.6.0 "*error #7986: A use associated object that has the PROTECTED attribute shall not appear in a variable definition context.*". So, either is a bug on both main compiler developers, either it is thought to be like that (e.g. like one ingenuinely would expect it to be).

Comment: @mEm Again: if the module array is declared `public`, `protected` , and not `target`, then all the requirements are met: it is readable but not writable. No need of any pointer or get function... If think the OP went to a wrong route from the beginning

Comment: @PierU I do agree with you, what I also stated in the original answer.. 
But, maybe for some reasons, he has to keep the `target`. Because as far as I understood, he then passes that important array to something which points to it, so that array has to be target. But not sure

Comment: The OP didn't really explain what were the constraints and why... We can just speculate.

Comment: "So, either is a bug on both main compiler developers": yes. Other compilers do accept this example without complaint.

Comment: @francescalus I have reported the issue on [fortran-lang.discourse.group](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/what-is-protected-supposed-to-protect-for-a-pointer/4759/6), and yes this is considered as a compiler bug. Someone will fill a bug report for ifort, and there are also gfortran developers there.